# Powerpoint Height of Histogram

Tags: powerpoint

In PowerPoint 2016 I have two histograms: one at 52% and the other at 48%. The last one is displayed half the size of the other one, but I want them both to display the correct size (i.e. one of them 52% of the total height and the other 48% of the total height).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've suggested an edit to your question to try to make it clearer (you can approve this to apply it to the question). In the meantime you could have a look at the [tour].

Comment: Look at the scale of your chart. PPT tends to modify the scale to exaggerate the differences between the data points. To accurately present percentage values, you may want to force the y axis to a 0 to 100 scale.

Comment: Hi Steve, it's working but i don't understand how to vote for your answer. Regards